# Insert date in oracle using prepared statemnt

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, oracle10g

My user interface returns a date as String (01/06/2016 2:30 am)to controller  and I want to insert the into **oracle 10 database**  by changing it from string to date and format to **(dd-MMM-yy hh:mm:ss a)** where the field is date type. Below is What I tried but getting `Illegal Argument` exception .

In controller I formatted to date and passed it to service layer through DTO

**created : 01/06/2016 09:00 pm**

```
SimpleDateFormat fromUser = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a");
SimpleDateFormat myFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy hh:mm:ss a");

String reformattedStr = myFormat.format(fromUser.parse(created));
System.out.println("reformattedStr is : " + reformattedStr);
```

**reformattedStr 06-Jan-16 09:00:00 PM

```
Date formateDate=myFormat.parse(reformattedStr);
```

In service through prepared statement i am trying to insert , the date and other fields.

stmt.setTimestamp (8,new java.sql.Timestamp(news.getCreated().getTime()));

Can anyone please suggest?

Thanks for the help , I have updated the code, it might help some one.

Comment: What is `news.getCreated()` returning?

Comment: FYI: [`Timestamp#valueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#valueOf-java.lang.String-) expects a `String` in the form of `yyyy-[m]m-[d]d hh:mm:ss[.f...]`, `java.util.Date#toString` may not return the value in this format

Comment: yes, , i did check that the format so tired to change the format to "yyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss a"  in controller and then try, but it still was throwing the same error. news is my data transfer object and created is the field

Comment: `Date` is a container for the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch, it does not have any format of its own. You should probably be using `new java.sql.Timestamp(news.getCreated().getTime())` assuming that `getCreated` returns a `Date` object

Answer (score 1):

If the column data type is `timestamp`, you don't need to do explicit conversion for the date. The `statement.setTimestamp()` method takes care of it.

There are two ways to create `TimeStamp` instance from a `java.util.Date` object.

```
new TimeStamp(date.getTime())
```

or

```
TimeStamp.value(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(date))
```

The value returned by the `news.getCreated().toString()` method might not be returning the correctly formatted date - if it's returning formatted date.

Please refer to the *javadoc* for `TimeStamp` class for more information.

Thanks

Comment: thanks, i have update the code and added the outputs in bold . can you please suggest.

Comment: Change SimpleDateFormat fromUser = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm a"); to SimpleDateFormat fromUser = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a"); HH is used for 24 Hour format and it'll skip the AM/PM part.

Comment: I figured it out why PM was chaning to AM . I changed the format fromdd-MMM-yy HH:mm:ss a to dd-MMM-yy hh:mm:ss a. Also updated the code above